# Multimap with duplicated keys ordered by order with which they appear in the given multimap

Tags: java, guava

I want to create multimap with keys as a Strings and values as a Sets

```java
Multimap<String, Set<String>> = ???
```

when I put keys, and values in this way:

```java
multimap.put("e", set1);
multimap.put("x", set2);
multimap.put("a", set3);
multimap.put("m", set4);
multimap.put("p", set5);
multimap.put("l", set6);
multimap.put("e", set7);
```

I want to receive exactly this same order with this same sets, so it means:

```java
"e" -> set1
"x" -> set2
"a" -> set3
"m" -> set4
"p" -> set5
"l" -> set6
"e" -> set7
```

I'm new inn guava, so could anybody write how to implement this Multimap to set duplicated keys in it and receive values in this order?

Comment: You can't put a Set as the value of such a Multimap. Only a String. It seems like you simply want a `List<Item>` or a `LinkedHashSet<Item>`, where Item contains two Strings. Please better explain what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Could I create `CustomObject` instead of `Set<String>` and use multimap? What I want to achieve is to have `String`s as a key (which will be duplicated, and some properties to each one. When I returned keys from map/multimap the order of inserting them must be saved.

Comment: @JBNizet: Sure, you can use a `Set` as the value of a `Multimap`, you'll just get something like a `Map<Key, Set<Set<Value>>`.  But that may not be what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LinkedHashMultimap.entries()` preserves the exact order the entries were added to the multimap.

Comment: and what about storing duplicated keys? From Javadoc _Class LinkedHashMultimap: Implementation of Multimap that does not allow duplicate key-value_

Comment: It really depends what you want, about which you haven't been clear at all.  Do you want something closer to a `Map<String, List<String>>`?  A `Map<String, Set<String>>`?  A `Map<String, Set<Set<String>>>`?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I want something like `Map<String, List<String>>` or `Map<String, Set<String>>` with duplicated keys and with the exact order of adding.

Comment: What do you mean, "duplicated keys"?  `SetMultimap` says that if you already have the key `"foo"` mapped to the value `"bar"`, you can't add another value `"bar"` for the key `"foo"`, and `ListMultimap` doesn't have that restriction (because its "value collections" are `List`s, not `Set`s.)  But all `Multimap`s will merge all the values associated with any individual key.

Comment: I've just checked and `Multimap<String, List<String>> multimap = LinkedHashMultimap.create()` with `LinkedHashMultimap.entries()` resolved my problem. Thanks, and sorry for misunderstanding.